# How do you download a file in android's ndk?

Tags: android, android-ndk, streaming, download

I'm trying to stream a file from the net in android's ndk, but i just can't seem to find any information about downloading files in the ndk. How would i go about downloading a file? is there some sort of api for available for this? i can't seem to find any.

i came across someone finding a way to use curl, but i don't think that api is readily available on all devices.

Comment: Why would you want to do that from the NDK? Anyway, what have you tried?

Comment: i'm streaming a media file. I don't know what to try because there doesn't seem to be much info about this on the net. So far i've been able to stream a media file using opensl. everything works fine, except when i try to store the media file while its downloading. opensl's media player decodes the file to pcm, which can take over 100 mb for a song. I'd like if it could store the media file without decoding it, but that doesn't seem to be an option, so now i need to find a way to just download the file using another api

Comment: I insist: this is **VERY** easy to do with the SDK. Is there some reason you need to do that from the NDK?

Comment: i need access to the buffer holding the downloaded file while its downloading. communication between the ndk and java is pretty slow. I'm trying to keep the audio system (ndk) and user interface (java) as separate as possible as my application is multi-platform

Comment: i suppose i'd be updating the ndk in chunks anyway, so the interaction between ndk and java wouldn't be much of a problem, but i'd still prefer to keep the audio system separate

Comment: Downloading a file is not part of an audio system. An audio system should take care of the **audio** part, not the **network** part. What about downloading the file then feeding it to your audio library?

Comment: streaming the file is kind of part of the audio system... i know i said download, but i need access to the data while the file is downloading. i need to know how much of the file is downloaded, and how fast its downloading, so i know when i can start playing the audio, and for how long. i'll also need to know if i need to pause the playback if the download slows down or the playback is reaching the end of currently downloaded data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22994/discussion-between-m0skit0-and-iedoc)